# Does every point of minimum local has derivative equal to zero?

Tags: derivatives

I have to answer if it's true or false that every minimum point of a function happens where the derivative is null.

But I was wondering about $f(x)=|x|$ which clearly has global (local) minimum at $x=0$, but we're not able to calculate $f'(0)$.

So, is the affirmative false?

Comment: local minimum, not minimum local.

Comment: If the derivative exists, it must be zero (not counting the endpoints of the domain).

Comment: First you need the proposition to be completely clear, before you want to see if it is true or not.

Comment: @HereToRelax the proposition is exactly that: very minimum point of a function happens where the derivative is null.

Comment: Sure, but what kind of function?

Comment: @HereToRelax the proposition is exactly that. No more info.

Comment: Oh, you mean in your homework?

Comment: @HereToRelax yes